# How to convert powers of 2 number to multiples of 10 number?

Tags: fixed-point

I would like to create a function which converts powers of 2 to multiples of 10.
can anybody help in providing algorithm such that function should use only integers .. Should not use ang float variable.

```
FUN_Convert(100,524247,1024) /*100->10^2,524247->511.96*1024, 1024 -> 2^10*/
    {
      int a;
      /*Do calculation*/ 

      return a; /*calculated value 51195*/
    }
```

Comment: FUN_Convert(multiples of 10, Scaled value (powers of 2), Current Scaling);

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but I guess the formula would be b/c*a if the function call is FUN_Convert(a, b, c)